# how can i echo the results from xml file to user input box?

Tags: php, html, xml

I have a form that posts to an xml file. I would like to echo the results back to the form. Any ideas on this? Here is my php and my html? I'm not abbreviating so if someone needs help this is a working model...

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['lsr-submit']))
{
    header('Location: http://google.com');
}

$str = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><entrys></entrys>';
$xml = simplexml_load_string($str);

$name = $_POST['name'];
$city = $_POST['city'];
$state = $_POST['state'];
$zip = $_POST['zip'];
$email = $_POST['email'];

$hostname = $_POST['hostname'];
$domain = $_POST['domain'];
$nameserver = $_POST['nameserver'];
$ipaddr = $_POST['ipaddr'];
$netmask = $_POST['netmask'];
$gateway = $_POST['gateway'];
$ntpserver = $_POST['ntpserver'];
$tz = $_POST['tz'];


$name = htmlentities($name, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8', false);


$xml->customer = "";
$xml->customer->addChild('name', $name);
$xml->customer->addChild('city', $city);
$xml->customer->addChild('state', $state);
$xml->customer->addChild('zip', $zip);
$xml->customer->addChild('email', $email);

$xml->emulator = "";
$xml->emulator->addChild('hostname', $hostname);
$xml->emulator->addChild('domain', $domain);
$xml->emulator->addChild('nameserver', $nameserver);
$xml->emulator->addChild('ipaddr', $ipaddr);
$xml->emulator->addChild('netmask', $netmask);
$xml->emulator->addChild('gateway', $gateway);
$xml->emulator->addChild('ntpserver', $ntpserver);
$xml->emulator->addChild('tz', $tz);

$doc = new DOMDocument('1.0');
$doc->formatOutput = true;
$doc->preserveWhiteSpace = true;
$doc->loadXML($xml->asXML(), LIBXML_NOBLANKS);
$doc->save('customer.dat');

?>
```

and the html

```
<form name="lsrReports" action="xml/process.php" onSubmit="return  defaultagree(this)" method="post">
<table width="50%" align="center" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
<td> name:</td><td> <input type="text" name="name"  required /></td>
</tr>
</table>

</form>
```

I only included the 'name text input box. so I was wondering how do I echo into the value attribute the results from the xml file? That way I have a form that is easy to edit. :)

Comment: Is your question how to get a PHP output into HTML? Or how to get the XML from `$doc`? `echo $doc->saveXML();`

Comment: No I'm trying to echo the info in the xml form back to the user input box... I'm almost there but not quite :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your HTML:

```
<form>
    <input type="text" value="<?php echo $doc->saveXML(); ?>" />
</form>
```

Of course, $doc must have been defined before that line. You might want to use a textarea instead.